# make an image animate dim and bright with css

Tags: image, css, css-animations

i want an image to get animated dim and bright simultaneously.

Should i use `.gif`/`flash` or is it possible with `css`?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it´s possible. Try with this code.

```css
.logo{
  animation: logo-animation linear 4s;
  animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: logo-animation linear 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation: logo-animation linear 4s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation: logo-animation linear 4s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation: logo-animation linear 4s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count:  infinite;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes logo-animation{
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0.990099773451273;
  }
  101% {
    opacity:0.99;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes logo-animation{
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0.990099773451273;
  }
  101% {
    opacity:0.99;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes logo-animation {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0.990099773451273;
  }
  101% {
    opacity:0.99;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes logo-animation {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0.990099773451273;
  }
  101% {
    opacity:0.99;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes logo-animation {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity:0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0.990099773451273;
  }
  101% {
    opacity:0.99;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ab/Logo_TV_2015.png" /></div>
```